# Why does inner join of A and B produce more results than either A or B in Pig?

Tags: sql, hadoop, apache-pig

My understanding is that an inner join should take the intersection of A and B that has the same keys, so the number of results in the intersection should never be more than A or B. However, I ran a pig script, which should perform an inner join by default, that suggests there are more results in the intersection than A or B. What could possibly cause this?

```
OLD_count = FOREACH (GROUP OLD ALL) GENERATE COUNT(OLD);
NEW_count = FOREACH (GROUP NEW ALL) GENERATE COUNT(NEW);

G = JOIN NEW BY (X, Y), OLD by (X, Y);
JOIN_count = FOREACH (GROUP G ALL) GENERATE COUNT(G);

DUMP OLD_count;
DUMP NEW_count; 
DUMP JOIN_count;

-- Results (approximate):
-- (70000000)
-- (80000000)
-- (85000000) wtf?
```

Comment: If you have dupes on the values you're joining in both tables you can get more rows.

Comment: Number of rows returned from an inner join between two tables can be between 0 and (Number of rows on table1 * Number of rows on table2)

Comment: @ConradFrix Thanks, that could be it.

Comment: @SerifEmek, would that maximum value (Number of rows on table1 * Number of rows on table2) only be produced in the case that all rows in table1 and table2 had the same key?

Comment: @brian-schmits It is one of the cases. If you say get rows where keys doesn't match and no key field really matches then you also can get this number. But for a join you don't have to use key or foreign key fields. Even you don't have to write an 'on' clause. This is a valid join: select * from table1 inner join table2. Theoritacally first cartesian product of tables is derived. Then rows which matches your conditions are added to result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With joins, you get one result for every *combination*, so if more than one join is made for a given object, it will be returned multiple times.

Consider 2 teachers and 3 students, where each teacher teaches every student. There are 5 (2 + 3) entities, but if you were to join the two groups by their relationship, there would be ***6*** results.